# Reading inputs and printing variables - JavaScript and HTML 4.01

Tags: javascript, html, html4

I've just been testing some code, and I can't get this to work:

```
<HTML>
<head>

<title> Page 1 </title>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementById("myEmail")
document.write(x)
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form>
<p> Input your email </p>
<input name="myEmail" type="text">
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit Email</button>

</body>

</HTML>
```

All I'm trying to is have the user type something into a text, being read by the parser, putting it into a variable, then printing the variable on screen. It would help me a lot with other projects I've got on if I knew this. Can anyone help?
NOTE: I don't want to use HTML5 because it removes some of the tags that I like, so could we use HTML 4.01 or something?

Comment: There is not a single good reason to stick to HTML 4.01.

Comment: What tags got removed that you like?

Comment: getElementById? so, where is the ID ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1 is to use HTML 5, indent your code, and use semicolons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title> Page 1 </title>

        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myEmail");
            document.write(x);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <p> Input your email </p>
            <input name="myEmail" type="text">
        </form>

        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit Email</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Step 2 is to look at what’s being written, see that it’s `null`, intuit when `document.getElementById` would return `null`, and realize that there is no element with an `id` of `myEmail` in your document. It just has a `name`. Drop the form while you’re at it.

```
<body>
    <p>Input your email </p>
    <input id="myEmail" type="text">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit Email</button>
</body>
```

The next step is to try that again and realize that `x` is an element, not a string, and you want to get its value.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myEmail");
    document.write(x.value);
}
```

The “good future practice” steps are, in no particular order:

- Put your script at the bottom and stop using inline event listeners
- Put your script in an external file
- Use a `<label>`

If you’re not going to do something more useful than write the e-mail back, consider also using `document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(…))`, which will not obliterate the rest of the document. The DOM is really great.

Comment: I sincerely didn't expect anyone to go as far as to write half of what you did. +1 for putting another soul in the good track.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the input

```
<input name="myEmail" type="text" id="myEmail">
```

then write the value

```
document.write(x.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById returns the DOM element.  Printing the DOM element is not meaningful and its output may vary by browser.

What you want is to print the input value of the input field, so check the `value` property:

```
function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementById("myEmail").value
document.write(x)
}
```

Secondly, your HTML code does not have an ID attribute on the element, so the getElementById lookup will fail.  Add an ID:

```
<input name="myEmail" type="text" id="myEmail">
```

Regarding your note about HTML 4 vs. HTML 5.

> NOTE: I don't want to use HTML5 because it removes some of the tags that I like, so could we use HTML 4.01 or something?

That comment is interesting.  Without knowing specifically which tags you are referring to, I cannot say why they are removed, but I imagine there is likely an equivalent.  HTML 5 does not remove any capabilities of HTML that I am aware of.

That is like saying you won't drive a car with an automatic transmission because it doesn't have a clutch.

Comment: HTML5 removes some take that just make it more complicated

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add an id attribute having the same value as the value of your name attribute of input type="text" and modify your script to store value instead of the element itself.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Page 1 </title>
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
    var x=document.getElementById("myEmail").value;
    document.write(x);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <p> Input your email </p>
    <input name="myEmail" id="myEmail" type="text">
    </form>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit Email</button>
</body>
</html>
```